# which is memory consuming calling a method twice or storing value in variable and using it when required?

Tags: java

edit : people marking it with negative research effort. let me know in comments whats wrong with question so that I can re-frame or improve my question.

I need to validate 18 columns of a excel file in java. I have columns validations matching certain criteria combined in common methods which will return a string.I need to set the value in two separate beans.

should I store them in a string and use it twice or call the method twice. currently am calling the method twice.which is the best solution. This happens for 18 columns inside a for loop.

```
private String getAlphaNumericValue(String data, String colName, int length) {

    if (Validation.CheckStringNullAndEmpty(data)) {
        if (data.length() <= length) {
            if (data.matches(constants.ALPHA_NUMERIC_REGEX)) {
                return data;
            } else {

                corrected.add(colName);
                return Validation.AlphaNumeric(data);
            }
        } else {
            corrected.add(colName);
            if ((Validation.truncateString(data, length).matches(constants.ALPHA_NUMERIC_REGEX))) {
                return Validation.truncateString(data, length);
            } else {
                return Validation.AlphaNumeric(Validation.truncateString(data, length));
            }

        }
    }
    return "";

}



for (CsvBean bean : beanList) {

    CsvBean writeBean = new CsvBean();

    if (Validation.CheckStringNullAndEmpty(bean.getNo())) {

        writeBean.setNo(
                getAlphaNumericValue(bean.getNo(), "No.", 50));
        DTO.setNO(getAlphaNumericValue(bean.getNo(), "No.", 50))

    } else {

        writeBean.setNo("");
        DTO.setNO("");
    }
//for 18columns am doing same validation

blist.add(writeBean);
zlist.add(DTO)
}
```

Let me know what is the best practice? what is the performance degradation and which is efficient either storing it in string vs method call. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its much better to store `String` in variable. In that way, you avoid to do the same job twice(calling your validation 2 times). "Penalty" is that you will allocate place for one String in your stack memory but that is really not the problem.

Comment: In my current scenario : It will take 36 method calls  * O(n) for loop times vs (18 method calls + 18 strings )* O(n) for loop times as per your suggestion when the file has (n) rows. correct me if am wrong.

Comment: I am not 100% sure what is your question, but I think this might be an answer. When you enter method, you allocate space on your stack. When you exit your method, that piece of memory is not allocated anymore. So if you allocate one String per method call, you will never have 36 in the same time in memory if you call your method 36 times. You can google "Java memory model" and you will find how Java allocate memory. You will end up with something like this: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/java-memory-model.html